# Custom game controller - button trace conductive coating

Tags: trace, controller, electrically-conductive

I'm attempting to make a custom controller for an old game console, and I'm looking for a way to replicate the conductive coating on the traces for the button pads:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/CsCwdQJ.jpg]

I'm harvesting the silicone pads from some old broken controllers for use in my custom one, and plan to have a custom shell/buttons resin-printed, I just need help figuring out what to use for the trace coating. Does anyone know of a product that could be used for this?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310212/silicone-keypad-design-problems

Comment: Just a comment: If it is going about few buttons maybe even hall sensors + magnets on springs would be better option. It last “forever”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a layer of conductive carbon ink.  The process is available from some PCB fab houses (usually as a custom order item), or you could buy and screen-print the ink yourself.

I wouldn't suggest hand-painting it, as it's likely to come out rough, or not adhere well (crack/flake?).  Needless to say, surface prep is important regardless.

I don't know the over/under of using other materials (conductive silver epoxy for example), and it may be that some of those are usable, durable, as well.

Comment: You can also use anything else conductive and non-oxidizing for this; using a hard gold plating for the PCB, while expensive, would also work.

Comment: Thank you very much!